# Creating a certain struct at run time in c

Tags: c, int, runtime, variable-assignment

I have an assignment for which the user will specify at run time the type of struct that they want to create.

For instance, lets say that the user inputs:

name : char[50], address: char[50] and age: int

Then my program will have to create a struct containing these 3 types of variables. Note that the user can specify as many variables as they want for the struct, only limiting them to char and int.

How should my code be in order to create a struct as specified above?

This is for c programming language only!

Comment: C is a statically typed language; your program will need to implement an interpreter (minimally), or a full compiler.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch actually, it has no strong typing, but a static typing. These are different things. As per your comment, agreed: I don't think (s)he can do it in a simple way.

Comment: You probably don't really mean a `struct`. But, you can create a *dictionary* or an *associative container* that can allow you to associate properties to field names. What the user is specifying at runtime is sometimes called a *schema*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

a variable have 3 fields: 
1) type, 2) name, 3) address. 
you shuold create an array of struct containing these 3, array of this struct will be what you want

your structs may look like this:

```
typedef enum _Type{T_INT,T_STRING}Type;
typedef struct _var{
  Type type;
  char* name;
  union {int n; char* str;} data;
}var;

typedef struct _Struct{
  int count;
  var* array;
} Struct;
```

when you get the input, you need to build the `Struct` according to it.
name : char[50], address: char[50] and age: int

```
Struct *s = malloc(sizeof(Struct));
s->count = 3;//count of fields in the input
s->array = malloc(s->count*sizeof(var));
//you really should do it in a loop, after parsed the input...  
for(i=0;i<s->count;i++){
  s->array[i].name = strdup(parsedname);//"name", "address", "age"
  s->array[i].type = strcmp(parsedtype,"int")?T_STRING: T_INT;
  //for string you need to alloc memory for string...
  if(s->array[i].type == T_STRING)
    s->array[i].data.str=malloc(50 /*the size you've got*/);
  //not need to alloc memory for the int
}
```

when you finish don't forget to free the mallocs:

```
for(i=0;i<s->count;i++){
 free(s-array[i].name);
 if(s->array[i].type == T_STRING)
   free(s->array[1].data.str);
}
free(s->array);
free(s);
```

You'll also need a method to fill the struct and print it, and so on...

Answer (score 2):

I have been wondering about this myself, because I was thinking about writing an FFI implementation for a language. (Although I suspect, based on your accepted answer, that your use case is somewhat different).

As pointed out, structs can only be generated at compile time, but this is primarily also a feature of the C language to enable type checking and so that type safety can be enforced.

At run time, you can still manipulate areas in memory as raw bytes. You just need to know the length and offset based on the individual components of the datatype you are declaring and manage these at accordingly.

I picked this up from looking at how the Ruby FFI library was implemented. The following is from their documentation:

> When you call Struct.new, it allocs an “internal bytes” worth of
>   memory right then. When you then do a set, like struct[:member] = 3,
>   the bits within that struct are set right then. The inverse is also
>   true; x = struct[:member] does a read from the raw memory (and
>   translation into a ruby object), each time you access it. Memory is
>   “zeroed out” when it is first allocated, unless you pass in your own
>   Pointer or specify it to not clear memory (additional notes). If you
>   pass it a Pointer it basically uses that as its base instead of
>   allocating anything.

https://github.com/ffi/ffi/wiki/Structs#when-allocated

Answer (score 0):

"only limiting them to char and int"

So you can create general datatype (struct), holding a list of nodes with name and char*, and a list of nodes with name and int.
On each new input you just fill the lists with required number of char* and int nodes.

To access the field of such data structure you'll need to traverse the list, although.
If you need efficiency, you can replace list to map (associative array). You'll need to implement it yourself as you are on C.